# Python Log, Not Writing to File

Tags: python, logging

So I am trying to implement logging within my Python program.  The goal is to set it up so that a log file is created and everything the program does through it's various modules is logged (based on logging level).  This is what my current code looks like:

Text File for Log Configuration:

```
#logging.conf
[loggers]
keys=root,MainLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_MainLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=MainLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(filename)s-%(funcName)s-%lineno)04d | %(message)s
```

External Module to Test Logs:

```
#test.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def testLog():
    logger.debug("Debug Test")
    logger.info("Info Test")
    logger.warning("Warning Test")
    logger.error("Error Test")
```

Main file:

```
#__init__.py
import logging
import logging.config
from datetime import datetime

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf', disable_existing_loggers = False)
logger = logging.getLogger('MainLogger')
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('{:%Y-%m-%d}.log'.format(datetime.now()))
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(lineno)04d | %(message)s')
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import test
    logger.debug("Debug Test")
    test.testLog()
```

Currently, all log messages are currently being displayed withing the IDLE3 shell when I run `__init__.py` and the log file is being created.  However within the log file itself the only message being recording is the "Debug Test" from `__init__.py`.  None of the messages from the `test.py` module are being recorded in the log file.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `test.py` it grabs a `logger` object before you configure it later in your `__init__.py`. Make sure you configure the logging module first before grabbing any logger instance.

Comment: Would a solution to this be to move the `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` line to inside of the `testLog()` method?  with that said would that mean for every method in every Module I use I should start the method by creating a logging object that exists over the scope of that method?

Comment: No that doesn't help because you're getting a logger object outside of the function.  What will help is moving the ``fileConfig`` call to the top level in your ``__init__.py``, *before* importing test,  so that it is the first thing ever to be executed when your package is loaded

Comment: Ahh alright.  So import the logging libraries, implement the logging stuff, the import and run everything else.  Gotcha

Comment: yes, have a look here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules

Comment: Well then that means you didn't do it correctly. Hard to tell now. Make sure you configure the  logger before doing anything else.    Or perhaps your logger configuration is incorrect. It is a bit weird that you have the configuration in a config file *and* doing additional configuration in your code. Try moving it all to the config file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150831/discussion-between-skitzafreak-and-irmen-de-jong).